# Инструментарий Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Как я могу сделать удобную и понятную иерархию?

Я хочу, чтобы у меня была возможность добавлять иерархию страниц, например:
Есть главная страница, на ней указаны ссылки на учебники:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
По нажатии по нужному учебнику открывается список уроков:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
После идет сложность заданий:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
И только после нажатия на какую-либо из сложностей открывается запись с заданиями для учеников.

Заранее благодарю за любую помощь, я ламер в этом деле, не бейте.

Comment: Если делать всё по уму, что это задача не для нуба. А неправильно сделать легко - просто создаёшь страницы в соответствии с нужной иерархией. Только потом переделывать будет больно.

Comment: @SeVlad это должны быть не страницы,  а вложенные категории. Шаблон категории выводит только дочерние категории, если они есть. А если нет - то страницы этой категории. И всё получается просто.

Comment: Тоесть мне просто нужно разобраться с иерархией рубрик?

Comment: @KAGGDesign там не только категории нужны, там и метки и кастомные сущности и логику надо отработать и связи.. Описанное ТСом - это ж вершина айсберга.